# Function App keys noting being created for new Function App

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm deploying a Storage Account and Function App via an ARM template, but after a successful deployment, I'm unable to use the the Function App because no keys are being created.

> We are not able to retrieve the runtime master key. Please try again later.

From what I understand (see this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/335)), there should be a folder created in the associated Storage Accont that contains `hosts.json`: **storage-account/azure-webjobs-secrets/function-app**.  However, this folder does not exist.

I was hoping that upon deployment of a Function, `hosts.json` would be created.  I believe there should also be a file named `FunctionName.json` that contains Function specific keys, but still the aforementioned folder does not exist and neither does this file.  This leads to an additional error being displayed.

> We are not able to retrieve the keys for function FunctionName. This can happen if the runtime is not able to load your function. Check other function errors.

Just in case anyone from MS picks this up, both errors should hopefully be recorded under Session ID **a814072a75d643d89c71d64d20c3dd55**.

Is there some bug with Function App deployment via an ARM template, or am I doing something wrong?

---

## ARM Template

Can be found in this [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/uC05f3jz)

## Example output

```
DeploymentName          : DEV-FunctionAppName
ResourceGroupName       : a-resourece-group
ProvisioningState       : Succeeded
Timestamp               : 02/10/2017 10:30:28
Mode                    : Incremental
TemplateLink            : 
Parameters              : 
                          Name                 Type                       Value     
                          ===============      =========================  ==========
                          environment          String                     DEV       
                          environmentSettings  Object                     {
                                                                            "applicationInsightsName": "service-name-app-insights",
                                                                            "functionAppName": "DEV-FunctionAppName",
                                                                            "storageAccountName": "servicenamedevstorene"
                                                                          }
                          serviceName          String                     Service Name
                          location             String                     northeurope
                          serverFarmName       String                     NorthEuropePlan
                          storageAccountSku    Object                     {
                                                                            "name": "Standard_GRS",
                                                                            "tier": "Standard"
                                                                          }
                          tags                 Object                     {
                                                                            "Application": "Service Name",
                                                                            "Environment": "DEV"
                                                                          }
                          
Outputs                 : 
DeploymentDebugLogLevel :
```

Comment: I've had the same problem when deploying an ARM template via VSTS RM. This also happens when 'updating' the environment with the ARM template. So if you create your environment manually everything works fine. When a release is finished and 'upgrades' the environment, the same error occurs.